# creating a new customer-endless compile errors using Visual Studio compile

Tags: c++

guys what am i doing wrong here i need to create a new customer using a int main to call it, code below.....visual studio compiler just has endless errors can anyone offer a fix? thanks so much. hopefully this is enough detail...

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <iomanip>
> #include <string>
> #define CUSTOMER_H
> #indef CUSTOMER_H
>
> using namespace std;
>
> struct customer
> {
>   string name;
>   string pin;
>   string user_id;
>
> };
>
> int main ()
>
>
>
>  {customer* CreateCustomer(const string& name, const string& id, const string& pin); 
>
>  return new customer{ name, id, pin };
>
>  cout << new customer << endl; }
>
>
> {
>                 customer* Mary = CreateCustomer("Mary Jones", "235718", "5074");
> }
>
>            return customer;
> }
> ```

Comment: Well, for one, you're defining a function inside a function. You can't do that in C++. ``cout << new customer << endl;`` is just completely wrong syntactically, and is never reached because you've already hit ``return``. The ``CreateCustomer`` function itself is completely redundant because you could just define a constructor for the ``Customer`` struct that does the assignment. In general, I recommend you read some basic C++ tutorials based on this code.

Comment: Thanks aruisdante, well i knew I was far of i am a beginner struggling to find examples that relate directly what I need so i was kinda hoping for a example to say "this is how its suppose to look" not so i can copy and paste it but rather so i I can see the flow of code and know for the future if something dont look right. but thanks for the comment anyway.

Comment: Sure, and don't think I meant to offend. But my point was simply that this code demonstrates a lack of grasp on the basics of C++'s syntactical rules which reading through something like [this intro to C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) will help immensly with. C++ is the kind of language where simply finding code that's 'similar' to what you want to do and cludging it to fit your problem without understanding exactly what is going on will lead to nothing but disaster.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will but this will be the last time. aurisdante was correct you do need to get a book on C++ programming if you are going to pursue programming. My initial response was a) because I remember when I was starting out. And B) to give you something that would at least compile. So, from here on out it is up to you to go forth and conquer...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

#ifndef CUSTOMER_H //CUSTOMER_H not defined
#define CUSTOMER_H //define it
#endif // CUSTOMER_H

using namespace std;


struct customer
{
    string name;
    string pin;
    string user_id;

};
//You have to do this after you prototype the object so the complier knows what the object is
customer* CustomerCreator();
customer* CustomerCreator(string name, string pin, string u_Id);
int main()
{
    customer* Customer1 = new customer { "Mary Jones", "235718", "5074" };

    cout << Customer1->name << Customer1->pin << endl;

    customer* Customer2 = CustomerCreator();
    Customer2->name = "Put name here";
    Customer2->pin = "0U812";
    Customer2->user_id = "AnotherNumberGoesHere";

    customer* Customer3 = CustomerCreator("William Shatner", "UCC-1", "HMFIC");


    //this creates a break point
    _asm int 3;
    return 1;
}

//this just creates and returns an object custmer
customer*  CustomerCreator()
{
    customer* Customer = new customer();
    return Customer;
}
customer* CustomerCreator(string name, string pin, string u_Id)
{
    customer* Customer = new customer{ name , pin, u_Id};
    return Customer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

#ifndef CUSTOMER_H //CUSTOMER_H not defined
#define CUSTOMER_H //define it
#endif // CUSTOMER_H

using namespace std;

struct customer
{
    string name;
    string pin;
    string user_id;

};

int main()
{
    customer* CreateCustomer = new customer { "Mary Jones", "235718", "5074" };

    cout << CreateCustomer->name << CreateCustomer->pin << endl;

    //this creates a break point
    _asm int 3;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Frosty! You life saver i cant thank you enough! Can i push your assistance a little further? I know i must now create a new function that will initialize and return the new customer may i ask for you to show me how to do that or if not what type of function it would b ? Void?